# iOS - applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning - Why?

Tags: ios, memory, unity-game-engine

I'm working with a Unity project that is running on my iOS devices via Xcode, and I'm currently getting the error:

```
applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning()
```

Every second. Yet my memory usage is around 40Mbs, which is 4% of my memory. So how am I getting a memory error? It's also the only app running. There are no other apps running in the background.

Please advise?

Thanks.

Comment: And we're supposed to know the answer how? We have no idea what your app is doing. _You_ are the one with the project. _You_ are the one with access to Instruments. Debug!

Comment: My point is, should I be getting a 'applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning' with only 4% of my memory being used? Because that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Not only your app consume the memory but also there are so many applications and iOS component waiting for the resources.

Comment: I understand. Although I have no other apps running. Surely the iOS components can't be using up that much memory for me to get a warning on 4% on my own app?

Comment: My point is, I don't necessarily believe anything you're saying, and you're not even saying very much. You're speaking in general terms. Get specific. You are _doing_ something that is causing this; but you are refusing to say what it is. Moreover, Instruments will show you what your memory footprint is from moment to moment. So if you are not willing to give any information, you won't receive any help. So use the tools you have. Help yourself.

Comment: I was just wondering if it's not unheard of to be getting this warning even with 4% memory being used. Why would I be lying? The thing is, I am doing something very general. Within Unity, I'm opening up a scene with a couple of textures. Then I get the memory warning.

Comment: Humm, not sure what the issue was, but I restarted my iPad, and it works fine now :-/ Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen situations where allocated a lot of memory at once (or a lot of small amounts of memory quickly) will cause the app to receive memory warnings. Not sure why that's the case as you'd think it would be ok until you started using too much in total but maybe iOS doesn't like it as it could affect performance of other apps or the OS itself.